# Usage and origin of the expression “nice and”

Tags: grammar, etymology, phrase-usage

According to the following dictionaries the expression *nice and* is an adverbial locution which is used to give more emphasis to the adjective that follows:

According to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nice%20and) ***nice and*** is synonym of *very*

> very —used to emphasize a good or enjoyable quality
>
> - *The soup is nice and hot. Make sure your room's nice and clean. The library is always nice and quiet.*

and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nice-and) suggests that the meaning is:

> - pleasingly,
>   (altogether, in a pleasing way)

How did the above usage originate?

The conjunction *and* actually joins two adjectives, so how does *and* actually work here, changing the literal meaning of the expression?

Comment: There is a similar construction with certain verbs: _I will try and answer your question._  This expresses both the meanings of _try_ and _answer_; in analogy, _nice and_ expresses a positive sentiment. So the soup is hot, but it's good that it's hot. But I have no idea where this usage originates from.

Comment: Also, _nice hot_ won't work, as _nice_ by itself is an adjective, and so it would have to be _nicely hot_.

Comment: @OliverMason - I am not sure the similar construction in “try and answer” you cite is in any way related to the use of “nice and”, but that's a good point to make. I know that the appropriate expression would be “nicely hot”, but given the idiomatic usage of nice, I just wonder why you need the conjunction and to make it an adverbial phrase.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that a similar structure also occurs with some verbs. Calling it an adverbial phrase is one way of describing it, alternatively you could just say the whole phrase is two adjectives linked by a conjunction.  AFAIK it only really occurs with _nice_, so traditional grammatical descriptions might not necessarily make sense. I would also not call it a synonym of  _very_. It clearly is used for emphasis, but more subtly than that. _I like my tea very hot_ is stronger than _I like my tea nice and hot_.

Comment: To generalize a bit, '__good and__ ADJ' also works  and 'good ADJ' is awful.

Comment: The soup is nice because it is hot. Probably something coming off of that.

Comment: I don't know how the use originated, but this is called "hendiadys". The collocation "nice and" is actually [the example that M-W uses in its definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hendiadys).